# WiFi can't connect despite type in correct password

Tags: wireless

I installed the 32 bit Ubuntu 15.10 on my laptop.It detected a list of wireless networks, then I tried to connect, I type in my WiFi password, it tries to connect for a while, about 6 second later, it pops up a prompt asking for password again, I verified that my WiFi password entered is correct, keep asking for a password.

I even rebooted my router.

Please help, thank you.

Here's output for lspci -knn |grep Net -A2:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1713] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo IdeaPad S10e [17aa:3a23]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
[14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:04b5]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: What is Ubuntu 15.12? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I attached the lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 command output. Sorry, it's latest version of Ubuntu desktop 32 bit 15.10. Thanks.

Comment: one is the Ethernet adapter, 2nd one is wireless adapter, no duplicates.

Comment: @rvpals: Your question is about the wireless controller whose chipset was made by Broadcom and the output of `lspci` shows that it doesn't use the right driver module. Your question is a duplicate of the linked question and very much so.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, thanks for the comment. Appears that it's a problem with wifi router not doing wireless b/g broadcasting. Once that's changed on my router (putting in mixed mode), I have no problem connect or using wireless network. It appears that driver that ubuntu 15.10 installed by default works, the problem lies in my router. This wireless adapter is on an older laptop that only supports b/g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu tried to connect to my router repeatedly and kept prompting me for password even though I type in the correct password.

Turns out the broadcom driver that comes with Ubuntu 15.10 is fine. The problem is with my router. My wireless router is configured to broadcast only in 802.11 N only figuring that I don't have any older adapter that needs b/g support. My lenovo laptop is using broadcom wireless adpater that only supports the b/g, not N. As soon as I set my router to broadcast in mixed mode, I can connect to my wireless network successfully.